# Group by Data Field

Tags: reactjs

I have a list component contains SUBJECT, NO, DESCRIPTION fields. For example: ACC 121, descr.., ACC 121 descr..., ACC 122 descr... ACC 211 desc.... How do I group by the same SUBJECT and NO in  tag and DESCRIPTION in sub components?

```
Courses=[{id:1, SUBJECT: ACC, NO:121,DESCR: 'class description1'}, 
         {id:2, SUBJECT:ACC, NO:121, DESCR:'class description2'},
          ...]  

const CourseList=({Courses, onCourseSelect})=>{

const renderedList= Courses.map(course=>{
    return (
    //add <h2>{course.SUBJECT} {course.NO} ???
    <CourseItem key={course.ID} descr={course.DESCR} onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect}  ></CourseItem>
    );
})
return <div className="List ui relaxed divided list">

{renderedList}</div>
```

}

-----EDITED CODE

```
var _ = require('lodash');
const CourseList=({Courses, onCourseSelect})=>{
let renderedList = _.groupBy(Courses,  'SUBJECT','NO');
 console.log(renderedList);
```

object list like below:

```
ACC: (26) […]
0: Object { ID: 1079, DESCR: "class description1", … }
1: Object { ID: 1080, DESCR: "class description2",  … }
2: Object { ID: 1081, DESCR: "class description3",...}
```

​​
How to render each object? I tried:

```
return <div>
 {Object.keys(renderedList).map(key => (
{renderedList["SUBJECT"]}
 </div>
```

but it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: If the list is not made up of objects then accessing it as you are doing will not work. Can you give a representation of the list having the fields you are refering to?

Comment: The Courses is an array of JSON objects with fields like [{id:1, SUBJECT: ACC, NO:121,DESCR: 'class description1'}, {id:2, SUBJECT:ACC, NO:121, DESCR:'class description2'},...]  Thanks.

Comment: In that case you are doing it correctly, What is the error you get when you run the above code?

Comment: It does not group now. I want to display like  *Group 1*
    - Item 1
    - Item 2

    *Group 2*
    - Item 1
    - Item 2

Comment: you should consider writing a helper function to sanitize and structure the Course array into a form that is ready to be passed to the `CourseList`

Comment: Let me come up with one in a post.

Answer (score 0):

The Idea is to do something like this.  Create a helper function to restructure the data into a multidimensional array by grouping them so that each array in the multidimensional array holds records about courses with the same id. then loop through the multidimensional array and perform whatever logic you want to.

```
let courses=[{id:1, SUBJECT: "ACC", NO:121,DESCR: 'class description1'}, 
         {id:2, SUBJECT:"ACC", NO:121, DESCR:'class description2'},
        ...]  


//Where ever we want to print the first group we just need to call the CourseList with a single input from the multidimentional structured array asonst 

CourseList=(courses, onCourseSelect)=>{
//create another variable to hold the structured data
//this ensures that each key in the array is it self another array holding all the courses with that same id.
let structuredData = new Array();
 courses.map(course =>  structuredData[course.id] = (courses.filter(co =>(co.id == course.id ))))
  <div className="List ui relaxed divided list">
    structuredData.map((data, k) => {
      //each iteration over data is printing for a single group
      console.log("Group", k)
      data.map(course=>
        <CourseItem key={course.id} descr={course.DESCR} onCourseSelect={onCourseSelect}  />
      )
    })
 </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not good at ES6. I need time to digest this line code courses.map(course =>  structuredData[course.id] = (courses.filter(co =>(co.id == course.id ))))

Comment: I used lodash to group SUBJECT and NO two fields. my console.log shows the grouped object array but I don't know how to render it in react. ACC: (26) […]
​​
0: Object { ID: 1079, DESCR: "class description1", … }
​​
1: Object { ID: 1080, DESCR: "class description2",  … }
​​
2: Object { ID: 1081, DESCR: "class description3",...}
​​
3: Object { … }

Comment: Assuming the grouping is correct it's left only to map over the grouped items and display. so from your log above you can instead of doing `return <div>
 {Object.keys(renderedList).map(key => (
{renderedList["SUBJECT"]})
 </div>` just do `renderedList.map(item =>{console.log(item.SUBJECT)})`  where I have console.log, you can literally access any attribute on the item and what ever logic you want goes there.

Comment: The line  `courses.map(course => structuredData[course.id] = (courses.filter(co =>(co.id == course.id )))) `  simply means get all the items that have thesame id in an array which is what filter does, then set it to the structuredData array identified by the id of the element eg structuredData will at the end look like `[Array(1), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]`  where Array(1) hold all items with same id as 1 etc

Comment: Thanks! The lodash groupby is easier to understand and use. I used your code <div> {Object.keys(renderedList).map(key => ( {renderedList["SUBJECT"]}) </div> and it works now.